# Unique names for DataTemplate generated elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a datatemplate which contains a Button, is there a way I can bind the name of the button(say, to the containing grid rowid) to generate a unique name for each generated Button?

Comment: Question... what is this for?

Comment: our automation framework uses name for uniquely identifying controls right now.

Comment: How are the buttons generated?

Comment: data template is used for Listview rows, each row will show the button.

Comment: I think you can use the `ItemContainerGenerator` to add a `Name` property to each control when it gets created, but there's a good chance there's a better way of doing whatever you're trying to accomplish with a unique name.

Comment: I'm guessing you've added a click event handler to the buttons and now don't know which row the button came from? You can't actually bind to name and shouldn't really be doing it this way but you could use the Tag property instead of name if I'm correct in my rather large assumption.

Comment: I am just trying to give unique names to buttons so that  it works with our automation script.We could have used automationId or Uid, but  wanted clarity on whether it is feasible to bind unique name to each generated Button